# Getting started w/ Database programming

Tags: database, cocoa, rdbms

I'm brand new to stackoverflow and programming in general, and this is going to be a somewhat long-winded question, so please bear with me:

**Background: I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 on OS X 10.8.4 for all coding atm.**

I've been configuring databases on Filemaker pro as a hobby for a few years now (for those who aren't familiar with FM, think MS Access or similar) and am now looking into C++, objective C and cocoa in order to build a database free of any kind of 'parent' program like FM.

Specifically; I have used filemaker to configure a clients database incorporating POS and accounting features for a few small businesses. This, however, requires each user to already have filemaker installed in order to be able to run my db.

**Edit:** Perhaps a less ambitious question:
**What languages/libraries/APIs/etc will I need to learn in order to create my own front end for a MySQL driven database?**

ie, for a very simple start: A Clients table with columns: ClientID, ClientName and Visits table with columns: VisitID, ClientID (relational) and VisitDate AND a front end GUI for OS X capable of creating/editing/deleting/searching records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to write your own database. If you want to write some crude persistence layer where you're reading/writing files (or something similar), then that's fine.

Here is a link about why you don't want to write your own database: http://ayende.com/blog/162691/worlds-smallest-no-sql-database

If the main reason you don't want to use a third party database like Filemaker Pro is that it costs money ... there are tons of rock solid databases that are *free*.

Go check out SQLite, MySQL, Postgres, or even MongoDB.

Comment: I'm afraid "no SQL database" doesn't mean much to me at the moment. As far as I understand (and please forgive my ignorance here), SQL is a language for querying databases. But what actually creates them in the first place?
I may have worded my question poorly; this is more of a quest for knowledge. I'm more interested in learning _how_ databases work than in creating one asap that suits my needs.

Comment: Sure. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172925/how-do-databases-work-internally or other articles for how databases work internally. Also check out a site like this for really in depth explanations: http://use-the-index-luke.com/. I've found lots of great database primers at http://regulargeek.com/ as well. SQL is a language for querying. The internal mechanics are quite complex, but if you look around you'll find many of them have things in common - like using BTrees to store data. Hope that helps!